# Initialize all channels in a struct using reflect

Tags: reflection, go

I have some structs that contain some fields and some channels. I managed to dynamically fill the fields from a map, but how do I initialize the channels? I need to set the size of them as well.

```
type MyStruct struct {
    ...
    Out           chan *mypackage.OtherStruct `json:"-"`
    Quit          chan struct{}               `json:"-"`
}
```

Comment: You initialize them like any other struct field. Can you show en example of where you're having a problem?

Comment: `structValue.Field(i).Set(reflect.MakeChan(structValue.Field(i).Type(), 1))` solves it.